# Curl Error 28: Connection timed out after 150001 milliseconds

Tags: php, curl, drupal-8, behat

While executing a simple behat script I am facing an error as below:

cURL error 28: Connection timed out after 150001 milliseconds (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException)

Can anyone help me out with the correct solution. I have seen seen similar posts related and tried changing the parameter "CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS" to "CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT" in the CurlFactory.php file. But still not working.

Comment: Please, show us the page you are trying to CURL.

Comment: The TCP connect attempt times out after 15 seconds, there's something wrong that prevents you from connecting within a decent time period.

Comment: The page I am using is on my local host.http://drupal-8-3-7.dd:8083/